# Facing issue in getting HTML data centered

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML. I want to take this data in the middle of the page but am not able to do this.

I just want to achieve the same thing as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are referring a data as text based on the image you mentioned. you can use text-align: center in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, we need more details. It may be simple and you just need to apply a `text-align: center` to the element wrapper the text.

In future, edit your post to show us your code and a screenshot of what you have so far. Otherwise, we cannot give you much help.

Right now it looks as if you're asking us how to create something that resembles that image. Stackoverflow doesn't take kindly to that.